# Program to show dropdown method menu in PyCharm

Tags: drop-down-menu, pycharm, settings

Can't seem to locate a dropdown method menu on PyCharm as per the attached picture when you entered an (object) and there will be a list of (methods menus) which you can select from without searching for them.

[image: dropdown menu]

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean the **auto-complete preview** as shown in the picture, you can activate it by pressing **Strg+Space** at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! Learnt something new! 
Can it be popped out automatically or I have to enter **Strg+Space** all the time ?

Comment: Have a look at this site: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html
You need to set the "Show suggestions as you type option" in the settings: "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion"

Comment: Ctrl+Space for code completion.